# flow and mortar transition with shared components

Tags: mortar

I'm wondering if it is possible to make screens transition animation like Activity transition with shared components as it is frequently used in Android Lollipop and Material design.
Thanks.

Comment: Any lead on that? I'm investigating that one too.

Comment: Someone from square answered me here that there should be demo that demonstrate such case on GitHub soon, but then deleted his post.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I didn't see anything related to that either. I just use those default android animations like slide_out_left for now.

Comment: Any news? Also investigating about this